# C# criando uma propriedade em um UserControl

Tags: c#, combobox

Tenho um projeto no C# e criei um `usercontrol` com dois componentes: um `combobox` e um `button`. Eu preciso criar uma propriedade para alterar as propriedades do combobox do usercontrol.

Eu tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
 public ComboBox Combo
 {
     get
     {
        return cboLista;
     }
     set
     {
        value = cboLista;
     }
  }
```

A propriedade aparece, eu consigo fazer as alterações no controle mas ele não **salva** e quando executo a aplicação as configurações do `combobox` não funcionam.

Answer (score 2):

Erro de sintaxe eu acredito: Inverte no `Set` `cboLista` e `value` e faça os testes!

```
public ComboBox Combo
{
    get
    {
       return cboLista;
    }
    set
    {
       cboLista = value;
    }
}
```

Bom uma dica quando se faz isso deve se preocupar com métodos e ações e por isso o seu `usercontrol` deve ter essas funcionalidades programadas. Quando usava isso em Web eu programava algumas ações que eu ia utilizar acionando o `usercontrol`.

Reforçando o que eu disse a programação deve ir até o objeto e ai você deve utilizar o UserControl como referencia para algumas configurações, vou deixar um exemplo:

O evento `Resize`, podemos configurar o tamanho do combo conforme o tamanho do `UserControl` dinâmicamente dessa forma:

```
private void UCCombo_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Combo.Width = this.Size.Width - 11;
}
```

Ao colocar o objeto (UserControl) ele vai deixar automaticamente o tamanho do combo dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, só concluindo, tem como ficar dinâmico, mas, a programação deve ser feita no objeto Pai

***Outro exemplo:***

Crie no seu `UserControl` um código assim:

```
public ComboBoxStyle ComboSytle
{
    get
      {
          return comboBox1.DropDownStyle;
      }
    set
      {
         comboBox1.DropDownStyle = value;
      }
}
```

Ao colocar o `UserControl` no seu `Form` ele habilitará essa configuração igual imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E mudando o `style` o controle mudará essa nova configuração também.

Comment: Eu percebi o erro mas mesmo assim não funcionou do jeito que eu queria. Eu só consigo alterar as propriedades do combobox através do código, por exemplo:

`cboTeste.Combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`

No modo visual a propriedade **Combo** aparece na aba de propriedades, eu faço a alteração da propriedade **DropDownStyle** eu vejo na tela a modificação (ainda no modo visual), mas ao executar aplicação estas modificações não aparecem.

Mas já dá para continuar o trabalho usando via código, assim que identificar qual o problema para o modo visual eu posto aqui.

Comment: "`mas ao executar aplicação estas modificações não aparecem`" Isso parece propriedade sendo setada em algum ponto do código. O depurador é seu amigo.